# adapting bank information form based on country

Tags: bank, iban

I have a form where I need to ask for my users for their bank details to facilitate payouts. Aside of their account numbers, there are bank codes (e.g., Swift, IBAN, BIC, BSB, etc.). What kind of information is needed may differ per country. Hence, I would want that the form adapts itself for the required information based on the selected country. Is there some kind of dictionary or API available that I can consult for this?

Answer (score 0):

The IBAN is being adapted by many countries day by day.

This link will show you all the [counties that support IBAN](https://ibanapi.com/countries), either fully or experimental.

So I would suggest you have a check if your user selected one of the above countries, then use the IBAN required fields, such as IBAN, BIC, Account Number, Branch, etc ..., otherwise use the SWIFT based required fields.

You can also use [IBAN API](https://ibanapi.com/get-api) to prefill fields on your customer's behalf by just entering the IBAN.